# Styling the react-native-paper component in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-paper

I am using the TextInput component of React Native Paper. But I am getting the outline in the UI even though I am putting `borderwidth:0`.

[image]

This doesn't appears when we are giving the input (when the num-pad is on)

Can someone please tell how to remove this.

```
render={({field: {onChange, onBlur, value}}) => (
          <TextInput
            keyboardType="decimal-pad"
            autoFocus
            //type= "outlined"
            maxLength={10}
            left={element}
            placeholder="Phone Number"
            style={{
              width: s(250),
              height: s(35),
              borderRadius: s(20),
              backgroundColor: theme.colors.white,
              //borderWidth: 0,
            }}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            theme={{
              roundness: s(20),
            }}
            onChangeText={onChange}
            value={value}
          />
        )}
```

Comment: ==> You can also approve my answer for no more extended need for support from the StackOverflow community & also for my motivation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add these property of TextInput

> activeUnderlineColor="white"
> underlineColor="transparent"

Answer (score 1):

==> you need to add this also.

```
<TextInput
            mode="outlined"
            outlineColor=theme.colors.white
            keyboardType="decimal-pad"
            autoFocus
            //type= "outlined"
            maxLength={10}
            left={element}
            placeholder="Phone Number"
            style={{
              width: s(250),
              height: s(35),
              borderRadius: s(20),
              backgroundColor: theme.colors.white,
              //borderWidth: 0,
            }}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            theme={{
              roundness: s(20),
            }}
            onChangeText={onChange}
            value={value}
          />
```

Comment: Even after adding the `borderBottomWidth:0` I am still getting that line

Comment: Is there anything I need to add

Comment: @TanishGupta can you please remove the width and let me know if is it visible or not...

Comment: its still the same

Comment: @TanishGupta i have edited my answer please change it and it's works fine,let me know if not worked.